# How can I insert values of a list into a nested list?

Tags: python, list

I have nested list like this:

```
ll =
[[[0, 0.01655718859584843],
  [1, 0.03777621092166489],
  [2, 0.02162311536578436],
  [3, 0.02907007584458954]],
 [[0, 0.011912058415296719],
  [1, 0.07967490411502279],
  [2, 0.04067120278932331],
  [3, 0.05439173103552319]]]
```

I want to insert the entries the second list:

```
uu =
[4577911, 4577821]
```

into the index 0 of the corresponding sublist.

So into the first sublist of `ll` I want to insert the first entry of `uu` like this:

```
[[[4577911, 0, 0.01655718859584843],
  [4577911, 1, 0.03777621092166489],
  [4577911, 2, 0.02162311536578436],
  [4577911, 3, 0.02907007584458954]],
 [[4577821, 0, 0.011912058415296719],
  [4577821, 1, 0.07967490411502279],
  [4577821, 2, 0.04067120278932331],
  [4577821, 3, 0.05439173103552319]]]
```

However my code delivers weird results

```
tu = ([[[u + x] for x in t] for t in ll for u in uu])
```

How can I do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nested list comprehension with `zip`

**Ex:**

```
ll = [[[0, 0.01655718859584843],
  [1, 0.03777621092166489],
  [2, 0.02162311536578436],
  [3, 0.02907007584458954]],
  [[0, 0.011912058415296719],
  [1, 0.07967490411502279],
  [2, 0.04067120278932331],
  [3, 0.05439173103552319]]]

uu = [4577911, 4577821]

print([[[i] + k for k in j] for i, j in zip(uu, ll)])
```

**Output:**

```
[[[4577911, 0, 0.01655718859584843],
  [4577911, 1, 0.03777621092166489],
  [4577911, 2, 0.02162311536578436],
  [4577911, 3, 0.02907007584458954]],
 [[4577821, 0, 0.011912058415296719],
  [4577821, 1, 0.07967490411502279],
  [4577821, 2, 0.04067120278932331],
  [4577821, 3, 0.05439173103552319]]]
```